# C# OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target='_blank';"

Tags: c#, redirect, response.redirect

I am using `OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target='_blank';"` which works fine, but how do I assign the new window sizes?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of embedding the `.target` in this way, create a JavaScript function that will open the new window (using `window.open`) and pass in the wanted values.

Comment: The problem with this method is that code as it currently stands will still do the ASP.NET postback, but into a new window. Using `window.open` to open a new window will not post the response back to the form correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use in the code behind:

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:myFunction(500, 500);");
```

And then have a javascript function:

```
myFunction(var width, var height) {
    window.open ("http://mydomain.com", "mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=" + width + ",height=" + height);
}
```